# What are the fastest ways of getting XP/Coins?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

I've just gotten to the fight that I believe is near the end of the game, and I'm level 31. I'd like to at least get one more rank up before I fight the Bowsers (which I believe will be at level 37 or 38). Grinding one or two levels is horrendously painful, I mostly leveled up off of boss fights in this game.

That said, where can I get faster XP than just grinding the monsters near the Bowsers? Additionally, I suspect faster XP would come with faster Coins, where can I get that?

Comment: If you don't have the Shiny Ring from the Expert Challenges rewards, you could go get that. It massively boosts the shiny enemy encounter rate, and I'm pretty sure shiny enemies give more XP.

Comment: @user2357112 They do, but only because they're 10 levels higher than the normal enemy level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done was replace my current Battle Card deck with a bunch of XP+, Coin+, and Star Point generation cards. I then ran from the farthest point in Neo Bowsers Castle to the front of it, destroying all the enemies along the way. By the time I got to the North Mt Burr warp point, I was able to warp back to Neo Bowsers Castle and do it all over again. I got about 6 levels per character in about 2 hours. It's not fast, but it works.